# How to call a function from another file by taking function name from user in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, frontend, backend

let's consider i have 2 files a.py and b.py

> a.py contains function

```
def add(data):
    c=data+120
    return c
```

> and b.py contains code.

```
import a
funcname=input("Enter function name")
data=int(input("Enter value to be sent")
```

What i want is when user enter "add" as funcname and some value in data then add(data) will be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getattr`

```
import a
funcname=input("Enter function name")
data=int(input("Enter value to be sent"))
result = getattr(a, funcname)(data)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton you saved me big.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
from subprocess import call
#Add your code here
call(("python[replace this with 3 if it needs to run on Python3]"+data),shell=True)
```

The call function basically just runs the code the user has entered in the terminal, as you would if you entered python and then entered a function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i need to deal with files only , though i got my answer but you solution gave me a mew insight . Thanks